# update my header accroding to login state

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make my header show or not show some nav-item according to the login state(using v-if). However, when I route to the page that logged in,  the data to determine whether user logged in didn't update immediately, I need to refresh to update the data.

Expected:

1. before login, showing: Home Login
2. after login, showing: Home Listing Logout

Realistic:

1. before login, showing: Home Login
2. after login, showing: Home Login
3. Refresh the page, showing: Home Listing Logout

MyHeader.vue

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light sticky-top">
    <div class="container">

      
      <img id="HA-Logo" src="@/assets/HALogo_En.gif" alt="HA Logo" class="">

      <div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link to="/" class="nav-link">{{ $t('Home') }}</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link v-if="!currentUser" to="/HALogin" class="nav-link">HALogin</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link v-if="!currentUser" to="/SupLogin" class="nav-link">SupLogin</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link v-if="currentUser" to="/Listing" class="nav-link">Listing</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link v-if="currentUser" @click="logout" to="/" class="nav-link">Logout</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"><LocaleSwitcher /></a>
          </li>
          <button @click="check">bug</button>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
</template>

<script>
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import LocaleSwitcher from './LocaleSwitcher.vue';
import SideNav from './SideNav.vue';

export default {
    name: "MyHeader",
    components: { LocaleSwitcher, SideNav },
    data(){
      return{
        currentUser: Cookies.get('login')
      }
    },
    computed: {
      loggedin(){
        return typeof Cookies.get('login') === 'undefined' ? false : true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      logout(){
        console.log("Cookies.get('login'): ", Cookies.get('login'));

        Cookies.remove('login');
      },
      check(){
        console.log("loggedin: ",this.loggedin);
        console.log("typeof Cookies.get('login') === 'undefined': ", typeof Cookies.get('login') === 'undefined')
        console.log("cookies: ",Cookies.get('login'))
      }
    },

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lifecycle hook like beforeCreate go get data from cookies.

```js
export default {
    name: "MyHeader",
    components: { LocaleSwitcher, SideNav },
    data(){
      return{
        currentUser: Cookies.get('login')
      }
    },
    beforeCreate() {
        this.currentUser = Cookies.get('login')
    },
    computed: {
      loggedin(){
        return typeof Cookies.get('login') === 'undefined' ? false : true
      }
    },
    ...
}
```

beforeCreate is called immediately when the instance is initialized, after props resolution, before processing other options such as data() or computed.

Answer (score 0):

cookies are not reactive so Vue will not detect them changing which is why a refresh is required.  You will either need a library like [vue-cookies-reactive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies-reactive) or try a different strategy. One alternative could be to store the logged in user data in a store (e.g. vuex or pinia) so when the cookie is set, you also set data in the store, and since the store state **is** reactive if you watch that instead of the cookie you'll have the desired reactive update to your page.  Cookies (and localStorage) are still a good way to persist state across page refreshes so it's not a bad idea to use both cookies and a store.